# Does API store any data permanently that is my database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am creating a app what take credential from user and use that credential to extract data from a website. I think i need to use an API to do that. But I am not sure about API. So if I use a DB say mongodb does the API save the data permenantly that are extracted from the website.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429713/does-api-store-any-data-permanently-that-is-my-database/41431311#41431311) below help you? If so then you can consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Yes it  helped me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't take credentials from the user that you use to authenticate on another website to get some data on behalf of that user, especially when you don't know what you're doing which most likely seems to be the case. You should use OAuth for that. Refer to the manual of the API that you're using and never ask your users to provide any credentials used to authenticate on any third party service.